# Pass a custom class object to generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a class with two generic type variable T and E as follow :

```
public class AdjacencyList<T,E> {

        HashMap<T, LinkedList<E>> adj = 
                new HashMap<T, LinkedList<E>>();
        void addToList(T source, E dest){
            if(adj.containsKey(source)){
                LinkedList<E> list = adj.get(source);
                list.add(dest);
            }
            else{
                LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
                list.add(dest);
                adj.put(source, list);
            }
        }
    }
```

And a custom class whose objects I want to add in the `AdjacencyList`:

```
public class GraphVertex<T,E> {
    T name;
    boolean visited;
    ArrayList<GraphVertex<T, E>> neighbors;
    Color color;
}
```

`GraphTraversals` is the class in which I want to add the objects of `GraphVertex` to `AdjacencyList` (in method `createAdjList`) as follow:

```
public class GraphTraversals {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    AdjacencyList<GraphVertex<T,E>, GraphVertex<T,E>> a = new AdjacencyList<>();

        GraphTraversals g = new GraphTraversals();
        g.createAdjList(a);

    }
    <T,E> void  createAdjList(AdjacencyList<GraphVertex<T,E>, GraphVertex<T,E>> a){

        a.addToList(createAVertex(1), createAVertex(3));
    }
}
```

But the generic type of `AdjacencyList` is not supporting the custom object of `GraphVertex`. Why so !! And how can I achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the declatation:

```
AdjacencyList<GraphVertex<T,E>, GraphVertex<T,E>> a = new AdjacencyList<>();
```

You need to replace the T and E with *concrete* classes instead of using the template parameters.

BTW: have a look at the new computeIfAbsent-method in the Map interface...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should just be writing `a.addToList(1, 3)`, or using an `AdjacencyList<GraphVertex, GraphVertex>`.  Right now your vertices *are Integers*, and you need to pass integers in.

Comment: Even if I changed the type of `AdjacencyList`, m still getting this error : `The method addToList(GraphVertex<T,E>, GraphVertex<T,E>) in the type AdjacencyList<GraphVertex<T,E>,GraphVertex<T,E>> is not applicable for the arguments (GraphVertex<Integer,Object>, GraphVertex<Integer,Object>)`